# Is there any responding authority above moderators?

Tags: discussion, support

Our main site is moderated by moderators. Since some of them are busy and some are not active in moderation.

Is there any higher authority that generally responds on serious issues? If yes, what are the ways to contact them on potential issues?

Comment: Not sure. maybe you should post it on Meta.SE.

Comment: You can contact them thru this link: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/contact

Comment: I also think that it's time now to report. With the Mods being silent/inactive and more importantly almost all the avid users, who have built this site to its current state (saving very very few like you), are also inactive.

Comment: @Rickross True.

Comment: @hanugm if you didn't get a response in 4 or 5 days, let's post it on MSE. I am positive we will get a reply there at least.

Comment: @Mr_Green Yeah. I am waiting.

Answer (score 5):

### Is there any responding authority above moderators?

Yes! They are called **Community Managers**.

You can check list of all community managers in this meta answer: [Who is on the Community Management Team, and what do they do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/206319)

Useful meta post to learn more about CMs: [Employee profiles are now marked with a “Staff” indicator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331654/206319)

### How to contact them?

1. There is a contact section on every SE site. For Hinduism SE; You can visit this link: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/contact
2. They are also contactable via email. Generally they will mention their email ID on their profile page.

**Note:** *Expect delay in response because currently there is shortage of staffs and hence they are hiring:* https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here/2351469?gh_jid=2351469

Comment: Looks like this (Community managers) is a paid position, unlike (I am guessing) the moderators. That is good because they will definitely respond, even if there is a delay.

Comment: @kākatālīya Yes that's a paid position. And yeah they'll respond, just there is a possibility of delay because of aforesaid reason.

Comment: So the concern is that the current moderators are not active? Or is it that old users have lost interest? Or that some users have agenda? Or one or more of the above? I doubt if anyone can help with #2 and #3 is difficult to prove. They can certainly help with #1.

Comment: @kākatālīya Guess if #1 is taken care of, remaining thing will automatically sort out.

Comment: Just remembered, I contacted the SE team before through SE contact.. like 6 months back or something. Still no reply.

Comment: @Mr_Green Please read the "Note" part. There are 150+ site and very few CM. It's not possible to respond to all the concerns.

Comment: So how will intercession on the part of the CMs help? It's not like the existing mods are beholden to them, so chances are CMs will simply ask members to appoint new mods from within the community .. so prepare to find 3 that are willing to drink from the poisoned chalice!

Comment: @iruvar haha! election is another possibility. :)