# Please stop being homophobic

Tags: discussion

Irrespective of whether the posts have valid citations, I have seen comments and downvotes which made me felt as a community we are against LGBTQ. Downvoting a post if a person don't agree with the post is completely fine but downvoting or commenting with homophobic nature is highly not acceptable and it is pure discrimination.

Please keep your beliefs to yourselves and use this site only to share your knowledge but don't try to share your beliefs (or try to start a cult).

Here are some posts:

- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24717/2995
- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11544/2995

> @KeshavSrinivasan I have not downvoted but People including me don't endorse homosexuality. Some might have thought you are in support. — Mr. Sigma. Mar 1 '18 at 11:47

> @AmitSaxena no hate for Homosexuals but for Homosexuality. — The Destroyer ♦ Oct 9 '16 at 5:50

> Not hate, it is discouragement to homosexuality. Do you want people to worship homosexuals ? — Mr. Sigma. Feb 15 '17 at 16:50

Comment: conservatives of all religions speak the same language - no sexual deviancy, no intoxicants etc. the main difference between is the method of enforcement - wooden stick or iron stick.

Comment: @downvoters The downvotes are to show that you disagree with this or something else?

Comment: idk, i didn't downvote

Comment: According to the Manusmriti, people who engage in *svavarganuragam* are said to lose their caste and thus their karmic value. 8.369 says virgin lesbians should be fined and given ten lashes while a lesbian who has formerly commited it with a man should be shaved of her head hair and have two fingers of hers cut off. What one person thinks or what people in general think about LGBT is not relevant on a site that focuses on scriptural evidence.

Comment: I have positive views about LGBT too but if we are going to keep the "scriptures" rule, we have some trouble.

Comment: There is no problem with scriptures. The problem is with people here. One's beliefs are better to keep for themselves than trying to "disturb" others on this site. If they are answering a question that is completely fine (_I don't know how many times I have to repeat this_).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While this has been discussed in HSE chat with the questioner, I will repost it here.

There is nothing wrong in downvoting an answer because it is misrepresenting and/or inaccurate. As far as comments are concerned, I believe that SE code of conduct sufficiently cover it. I do agree that there are other ways to post that Hinduism is against homosexuality without sounding offensive.

At the same time I don't think it is a great idea to delete answers such as this [one](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11544/18974), because rejection of a view (down votes + comments ) also needs to be communicated.

Comment: This is a fine answer. If this is also a reflection of how you will moderate if you were to become a moderator, you should consider nominating yourself [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2019/2020-potential-community-moderator-election-community-interest-check).

Comment: @sv - Thank you. I will definitely consider. An important factor is time commitment and timely intervention. Inordinate delays is equivalent to no moderation. Will throw hat in ring if i am sure about it from my end.

Comment: 'An important factor is time commitment and timely intervention' - agree on that but the bar is really low considering the two other mods haven't commented or posted in a while on main or meta sites.

Comment: @sv -Yes, perhaps will get a better idea when moderator(s) respond to your [answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2019/18974)

Answer (score 6):

It is worthwhile looking at the [code of conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) on Stack exchange.

> **No bigotry.**

> We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, **sexual orientation**, or religion — and those are just a few examples.

Any comments against homosexuality or homosexuals would be against the code of conduct. Any such comments should be flagged for the attention of the moderators and if the moderators themselves are making such comments, it should be reported to the [community managers](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2010/17987).

Comment: "Any comments against homosexuality" - What about citing Hindu scriptural verses that say homosexuality is sinful?

Comment: @Ikshvaku That should be fine, I guess.

Comment: Of course it should be fine, as long as we don't violate the general rule: do not offend others.

Comment: @kākatālīya, how are scriptural verses saying 'homosexuality is a sin', not offensive ? on the other hand, i don't think they even believe in the concept of sin, so it probably shouldn't offend them.

Comment: @ram Even if someone finds them offensive, they can be quoted, because they are scriptural statements and this is a site about religion (Hinduism). It is similar to statements about caste.