# 2020 Potential Community Moderator Election - Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

It's time for us all to consider holding an election for a new volunteer moderator on Hinduism Stack Exchange!

Last time we had a [change in our moderator team was in February 2017](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/780/277) when two previous moderators stepped-down, and me and The Destroyer were appointed as new moderator pro tempore. Since then our site has been running well with three moderators, but the overall traffic and number flags count have increased gradually in 2020. Presently we get/handle quite more flags as compared to [2017's senario](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1083/277). So, we are thinking of increasing our moderator team by having one more moderator who can contribute to maintain the site clean and enjoyable.

Since 2017, [elections have become the default way to appoint pro-tems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314459/208518). To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, though, I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual election's nomination period starts.

**Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position**, should we decide to run an election.

Note: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up. Further process will be announced by a Community Manager.

---

<sup>Since this will be first community moderator election on our site you may want to visit and check [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135361/260388) to learn how moderator election happens on Stack Exchange.</sup>

Comment: Rolled back the edit, @sv. — it is superfluous to this particular interest check, as it's actually information that applies to all mods/elections/sites. It's best to try to keep the post a bit clearer on what the call to action here is: for folks to say whether they're willing to nominate if there's an election or not. You're welcome to leave a comment here linking to mine further down, if lack of visibility is what you're worried about :)

Comment: Very great step

Comment: I request people not to go with reputation alone. SwiftPushkar and TheLittleNaruto are good in my opinion. But some of the users with high reputation are misleading the site. Don't go with them.

Comment: I have been wondering how many moderators would be chosen. Two of our existing moderators are not active. I think we need at least two new moderators. Anyways, how is the number decided: By the community or by the staff?

Comment: @Archit Are you interested?

Comment: @hanugm, no thanks for asking. What about you? The site would be run well you’re active on meta too.

Comment: @Archit May take time.... Now slightly hectic with academics....

Comment: Sad to find that we hardly got only 2-3 candidates interested/ready for the role!

Comment: Hi @Pandya, would you be willing to share with us the data on number of flags/day at the time of calling this election, just like the 2017 post did?

Comment: @user1271772 As per past year analysis, 6 flags are being handled on daily basis. Btw, welcome to Hinduism  Stack Exchange! It looks you have joined few months ago.

Answer (score 18):

First of all thanks for addressing to all the meta posts which made recently about  "less participation by moderators". This is genuinely a good decision and a welcoming one.

We have good number of active users now, and I hope we will see a good number of participations from all users in the election as well.

I will consider myself to stand for moderator position to get an experience as mod and to serve community voluntarily.

Comment: why don't you throw your hat into the ring? Your biggest qualification being you lurk in the corridors of HSE all day, a quality that will stand you in good stead as a moderator ;-)

Comment: I will consider this as the nomination. I don't see why not you. upvoted.

Comment: +1 for participation

Comment: Thank you TheLittleNaruto for your consistently excellent helpful contributions, and for now volunteering to be a Hinduism se Moderator!  :)

Answer (score 9):

Yes. To begin with I would like to thank you for the much needed post. We all really love Hinduism SE! by heart and we sincerely care about the growth of the site , increasing activity as well as active user participation. We also remember those Happy Day's and those happy hours we spend here when the site was it's peak.
Anyway considering the current situation , your decision of inclusion of one more moderator to maintain the site effectively is very excellent in my point of view and i am with it.
This way we will be able to better manage the site while encouraging the active user  participation in site activities. A good and skillful new moderator will help in achieving this task by lending you people a good hand.

I am also in favor of conducting a free and fair election for the selection of our new moderator as well.

Comment: Sorry, I must ask as you are standing for a new mod. Why were you inactive all these months on meta (_ignore if it is personal_)? Just hoping this won't be the case when you become mod (_just don't want yet another inactive mod_)

Comment: Mr_Green - I appreciate your concern but while i was not participating on Meta ,I was fully active and were participating in site activities on main site. And please don't worry as i will not take your comment personally.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Glad to see you participating in moderation. Please join chatroom as well.

Comment: Glad you ready to be mod..we need mod who knows both SE features/rules and Hinduism scriptures...

Comment: What about you? IMO you are also a deserving candidate @YDS

Comment: As I said "we need mod who knows both SE features/rules and Hinduism scriptures"...and we have other users who r better than me in both the areas..u r one of them, u should nominate.. @Rickross

Comment: I can be away for months so I am a very bad choice. Pls nominate yourself @YDS

Comment: YDS and Rickross are also eligible people if they want

Comment: +1 for participation

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Don't see ur nomination yet on the Election page.. :)

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Are you not nominating yourself? I thought you were interested? Please nominate yourself. Still there is time.

Comment: @YDS - Thanks for support. Unfortunately I haven't decided yet.But still I will go for a second thought till last min. :-)

Comment: @Rickross- Thanks to you too bro. I will try. :-)

Comment: Thanks :) yes please see if you can make it. @SwiftPushkar

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Did you decide? If yes, please announce, hoping your participation.

Comment: @hanugm - Thanks , no I decided not to participate because I am not sure whether I can devote much time for the task. Currently It's  the best interest of the site that someone else become the MID who is present here  most of the time and that ultimately is important rather than become a MOD for me.  So not congested for best of the site.:-)

Answer (score 9):

I would like to join in as well. I really want to see Hinduism.SE get to graduation level soon.

**Why me?**

I am not biased or against anyone or group in this community. I usually prefer listening to others before explaining my understanding. I also admit if I make any mistakes and will definitely correct it.

You can definitely see me going with the community flow and trying to increase that pace.

Note: At first I thought not to join as I won't be regularly active on this site (*I visit at least one time in 3 days*) but seeing JNAT's comment I decided to join in (Also, as there is not much participation).

We need more participation!

Comment: Thanks for joining in. I wished to see you as a Mod. My vote will sure go for you. :-)

Comment: +1 for participation.