# Can one expect a new moderator in short time?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderators

There are atleast a couple of posts in our recent past about the need of increase in moderators.

And then a [potential question](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2019/2020-potential-community-moderator-election-community-interest-check) has been floated.

Community gave a grand welcome to the idea with 16 upvotes and two users: [TheLittleNaruto](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2020/661), [SwiftPushkar](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2021/661) announced their interest in participation. Each one got atleast 10 upvotes.

It is then obvious that community is interested in increasing the moderators. Are there any other criteria(s) needed to take the decision? Or will it take a while to make an official announcement as a response to the community interest?

Comment: We're a bit too late in the year to schedule an election in 2020: Thanksgiving is coming up in the U.S., and then December is always sort of a half month — these both generally mean reduced traffic on sites, as well as reduced staff capacity. As such, we're only able to schedule an election for y'all in January, but will work to prioritize it so it's one of the first of the year.

Comment: Almost time. Just wondering how many moderators would be chosen. Is it determined by the community? Is it determined by the staff? Recently, in history they chose 4, in politics 2, whereas in webapps just 1. I believe we need at least two because two of our existing moderators are not active.

Comment: @JNat Happy New Year! Looking forward to hearing from you soon :)

Comment: To you too, @Pandya — I'll be in touch with the team to schedule the election soon ;)

Comment: @JNat Seeing the [inactivity of other two mods](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/15189?m=56321324#56321324), removing them and electing more than one mod would be better option. Just my opinion. :)

Comment: I'll figure out what the moderation team's needs are with 'em, @TheLittleNaruto, and go from there ;)

Comment: Yes, I agree with @TheLittleNaruto. Seeing the current situation of HSE, We should have as many active mods as possible. Also, even if the two mods (Pandya +1) think they are unable to manage, I don't think we can see one more election anytime soon. FYI, Keshav is active here but not doing any mod work, and also Destroyer is not active here but active on another social site.

Comment: @JNat Any update on election schedule ? :D

Comment: Figuring it out with the moderation team right now, @TheLittleNaruto — hope to have updates soon.

Answer (score 10):

An election to bring some more folks aboard [has been scheduled](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2120/2711). Assuming it has enough candidates to run successfully, a new moderator should be added to the team once it is concluded.