# Announcing a Pro Tempore election

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Hinduism Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **February 1** to bring in one more moderator.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on February 1, users can [nominate themselves](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/election/1). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On February 8, if there are two or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidate. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on February 16.

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Comment: Thank you for the announcement :-) Quick question why we are not electing more than 1 mod? (Asking because of inactivity of other two mods)

Comment: We're going with one for now, given the two mods that have recently been inactive have mentioned they plan to ramp up moderation activity on the site. And we're doing so under the provision that we may call a runner up in a couple of months if there is a need for it.

Answer (score 9):

> The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected.

Better late than never, why isn't HSE graduated and then have an election? I don't think it is Area51 stats, considering other [religion SE sites graduation](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2094/93). Maybe letting us know what is being expected through a new meta post will be great, either by mod or cmod.

I have my own assumptions of what is being expected, but I don't think there is a general common understanding of it.

Comment: [This](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/a/444/6) is the most recent status update when it comes to graduation plans for the network.

Comment: Hi, @JNat any update on this? we raised the [same question again](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2279/93).

Comment: No new updates, @Mr_Green, no.

Comment: @JNat Is there any update on our main site as I heard that some news about graduation on other sites?