# My dream of graduation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

I always have this thought in my mind.

> When [our main site](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/) will get graduated

There are many questions, asked by several users, on this site regarding this. Still, due to my consistent thoughts on it, I want to discuss the following questions with other users.

Is there any deadline for graduation? I mean the day that our main site will any way graduate.

Who are the deciding members? I mean the members who have the capability of making graduation decisions.

How much far is our main site to graduation?

Is there any chance that our main site gets deleted (in any extreme case)? Did any site in the history of stack exchange network get deleted after this many years and this many users, questions, answers, etc.,?

Is it possible to accelerate the process?

**Recent update**:

Many sites are graduating: [AI](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2828/artificial-intelligence-is-graduating-becoming-full-non-beta-site), [MM](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298/matter-modeling-is-graduating), [QC](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/517/quantum-computing-is-graduating), [FL](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340/freelancing-is-graduating-in-december-16). But we didn't receive any update yet.

Comment: See [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2164/update-new-answer-right-below-where-have-the-votes-gone-a-reflection-into-th) Point 2: one of the possible reasons for non-graduation.

Comment: Maybe this will answer: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2121/93

Comment: Strange, I pinged @Catija on meta latin.se but seems the comment was removed as it is not related to that site (maybe). But I thought they will update here something (comment or answer) to make us not assume things for the time being at least. Hoping they will update soon.

Comment: @Mr_Green oh.... the same person who conducted elections....

Comment: Not sure who is in charge ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. I pinged @Catija who is another cmod.

Comment: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2120/announcing-a-pro-tempore-election/2121#comment10708_2121

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Dream is continuing........

Comment: Not sure about graduation but would like to see the "beta" label removed.

Comment: Your dream is going to come true! Visit [this post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2324/277) :)

Comment: Yahoooo..... Thanks @Pandya :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Abhinandanam! Hinduism Stack Exchange is losing the beta label on 16th of December!](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2324/abhinandanam-hinduism-stack-exchange-is-losing-the-beta-label-on-16th-of-decemb)