# How to know the site stat? For example, how many questions are asked per day?

Tags: discussion, statistics

How to know the site stat? For example, how many questions are asked per day? In one post, I read that due to the low number of questions per day this site is still beta. Just curious about the number of questions per day. Due to the new rule, a person gets 10 points if someone upvotes his question. So there must be an increase in the number of questions per day. How can I know this?

Comment: Hello, you can check on [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism). It is 12 questions per day now.

Comment: @Mr_Green thank you so much. It looks like the site is doing well except in one area, which is the percentage of answered questions. That needs improvement. Is this because of only this point the site is still beta? Why the site is still beta is answered a few years back. Now, why we are still beta?

Comment: Perhaps. we'll ultimately get the promotion based on the age factor, just like the other beta of Islam.SE got, I guess.

Comment: @AmritenduMukhopadhyay As per my understanding, there are some issues with community mods to handle the graduations - [There isn't much clarity on this to this community](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2279/my-dream-of-graduation). Also, as Vivikta mentioned it might take one more year to be eligible for graduation irrespective of the statistics, as being a religious site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) is a good way to get various statistics. (Although you'll need to write an SQL query using the [available database](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) - or find a query written by somebody else.)

> So there must be an increase in the number of questions per day. How can I know this?

Some queries related to this:

- [Number of questions/answers/posts per month](https://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/1223741/number-of-questions-answers-posts-per-month#graph) (It is probably better to take a longer period for averaging.)
- [Number of questions/answers/posts per day](https://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/1416687/number-of-questions-answers-posts-per-day) (This is a bit more difficult to read.)
- If you want to include the deleted questions, you can use the table PostsWithDeleted in the above queries. Or you can use this table if you want to check how many posts (answers/questions) get deleted.

---

As mentioned in the comments, some basic stats are available [on Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism). And for graduated sites, one can see them in the [list of all sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questions). Users with [access to site analytics](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) (which is [5k on Hinduism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260849)) can also see there some stats about traffic, number of posts and number of votes.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was actually looking for this. I can see the graph. I can customize it. Wonderful.