# Abhinandanam! Hinduism Stack Exchange is losing the beta label on 16th of December!

Tags: discussion, community, beta

Happy Deva Dīpāvalī & Kārtika Pūrṇimā!

One exciting good news (*Ākāśavānī*) has been conveyed from [The Stack Exchange Community Management Team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/260388): **Hinduism Stack Exchange is selected/qualified for the removal of beta label and for the graduation on 16<sup>th</sup> of December 2021.**

Based on longevity and number of useful posts, several beta sites are losing beta label & joining the other graduated site and our site will be one of them! Though official announcement will be there from Stack Exchange soon, *We (the moderator team) are very excited to share this good news with you'll through this post!*

Let's have a look at the major difference between beta and non-beta site from the help center article on [What does "beta" mean?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-beta):

> - All beta sites have the same temporary placeholder design. Once the site is no longer beta, it will have a unique design built with input from the community.
> - Reputation thresholds for [privileges](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/privileges) are lower during the beta phase to help ensure community governance early on.
> - In early beta, the Stack Exchange team [appoints moderators](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) until the site is large enough to sustain a [democratic moderator election](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work).

Now, talking about the design and reputation levels following is the message from CM:

> Currently, site design customization will not be part of the graduation process. We’re hoping that some lightweight customization for sites will be available in the future, but we don’t have a timeline for that right now. You will also retain your beta reputation levels.

Talking about site moderators, an election will be carried out in future of which result will determine the moderator team.

So, thanks to all the users who have been contributing in providing the useful content to the site and who are helping to make the site clean. And thanking to the community management team for putting efforts in reviewing beta sites and for this good news.

Comment: Congratulations to everyone for working hard for achieving this milestone and keeping patience.

Comment: Śrīrāmajayam, all the best to us.

Comment: Excited and expecting the change anytime now!

Comment: @Mr_Green Haha! stay tuned with MSE :)

Comment: Update: [Today, 58 Stack Exchange sites that originated in Area 51 will lose their beta labels.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/16/congratulations-are-in-order-these-sites-are-leaving-beta/)

Comment: Update2: [Congratulations!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374096/260388)